# How to find if it's Windows 10 1909 French or FrenchCanadian that was installed?

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

We have 2 different ISO that were used to install Windows 10:

SW_DVD9_Win_Pro_10_1909_64BIT_French_Pro_Ent_EDU_N_MLF_X22-17398
and
SW_DVD9_Win_Pro_10_1909_64BIT_FrenchCanadian_Pro_Ent_EDU_N_MLF_X22-17399

We want to eliminate the FrenchCanadian version so we need a way to find out where it was installed.  We use SCCM so if we could have a query to populate a collection with the computers running the FrenchCanadian version, that would be the best.  Could also use PowerShell to run scripts on every computer if that's necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome here! Did you think about running the Get-WinSystemLocale in powershell? Those with the French Canadian iso will have the FR-CA locale. (LCID 3084)

Comment: Was just about to suggest what @NatsuKage mentioned. Here is a link to the relevant docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winsystemlocale?view=win10-ps

Comment: Hi and thank you Natsu Kage.  I did in fact run Get-WinSystemLocale in PowerShell on both versions and they come out with the same information: Fr-CA (LCID 3084).  It probably comes from the fact that we selected the Fr-CA language on both versions at install.  So unfortunately, that command is of no use to tell them apart now.

Comment: Ok. I thought you wanted to use the French locale only. You can try **[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version** or **systeminfo** and see if they give a different result. source:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/how-to-find-the-windows-version-from-the-powershell-command-line/7330368

Comment: Ultimately we want to use the Fr-CA locale on the French ISO installations only.  So we need to get rid of the FrenchCanadian ISO installations.   You would think that once you select the Fr-CA locale on both ISO, they end up being the same, but no.  There's a difference between the French and the FrenchCanadian ISO installations even when both are configured to use the Fr-CA locale.  I tried [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version and systeminfo and it doesn't seem to give me exactly what I need to differenciate them easily.

Comment: It appears that `Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsBuildLabEx"` should contained the value you are looking for.

Comment: No sorry, that command gives the exact same result on both versions.

Comment: `Get-ComputerInfo -Property "OsLanguage"` seems to do the trick though. It returns Fr-FR or Fr-CA depending on which ISO was used for installation.  Thanks for suggesting Get-ComputerInfo Ramhound, it led me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-ComputerInfo -Property "OsLanguage" seems to do the trick. It returns Fr-FR or Fr-CA depending on which ISO was used for installation. Thanks for suggesting Get-ComputerInfo Ramhound, it led me to find the solution.